# Image textures appear dimmer in Blender renders

Tags: materials, toon-shading, output

I'm a video editor that use Premiere Pro to edit videos. However, I've grown to love the shader editor for Blender because it's so versatile. I tend to try some pretty crazy effects in Premiere that usually involve complicated masking, and when I'm tearing my hair out trying to think of a way to make things work I can't help but think how much easier it would be to do it in Blender. I know it's pretty silly to use Blender for 2D projects, but it gives me such creative control in how I approach textures.

So I cracked and tried to do some 2D video editing in Blender. I rendered out certain video elements, and am using them to create the scene in Blender. However, for whatever reason, Blender outputs a dimmer and worse image than the source files. Here's a very zoomed in portion of image for comparison.

[image]

Technical info:
The input image texture were non-dim lossless PNGs and the Blender output was also set to lossless PNGs. I understand that the scene lighting can affect the render and as such my node setup is just an image texture node plugged straight into the material output node.
Weirdly, the output PNG didn't render the transparency, despite me enabling transparency in the film settings and turning on alpha blend. That's odd.

Ethical implications of using a 3D software aside, is there a reason why the output from Blender is considerably worse?

Comment: Did you tweak the Color Management settings in the Render panel?

Comment: Thanks @AlpineWorldCup and moonboots. You're right, the image stopped being dimmer. However, the image quality is still worse.

Answer (score 2):

By default the [Color Management](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/render/color_management.html#render-settings) [View Transform](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/render/color_management.html#bpy-types-colormanagedviewsettings-view-transform) is set to *Filmic*. This allows for more high dynamic range in 3D renders. Change this to *Standard* and the dimness will go away.